# oracle trigger exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

Tags: oracle, triggers, syntax-error

I am trying to get the Quantity from the transaction table. Try to get the quantity of the sell and quantity of buy. Use Portfolio_Number, Stock_Code, Buy_Sell to verify the quantity.

```
Transaction Table (Portfolio_Number, Transaction_Date, 
Stock_Code, Exchange_Code, Broker_Number, Buy_Sell, Quantity, Price_Per_Share)
```

```
create or replace trigger TR_Q5 
before Insert on 
Transaction 
for each row 
declare
V_quantityB number(7,0);
V_quantityS number(7,0);
begin 

if(:new.buy_sell ='S') then 

select quantity 
into V_quantityS
from transaction
where :new.portfolio_number = portfolio_number
and :new.stock_code = stock_code
and buy_sell='S'
;

if V_quantityS>=1 then

  Raise_Application_Error(-20020, 'not S');

 end if;
end if;
```

try to insert

```
INSERT INTO Transaction 
(Portfolio_Number, Transaction_Date, Stock_Code, Exchange_Code, Broker_Number, Buy_Sell, Quantity, Price_Per_Share)
values
    (500, To_Date('09-Feb-2020 16:41:00', 'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'IBM', 'TSX', 4, 'S', 10000, 25.55 );
```

but it shows up the error

exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

Answer (score 0):

The error you mentioned is self-explanatory. `select` you wrote should return just `1` row, but it returns more than that. As you can't put several rows into a scalar `number` variable, you got the error.

What would fix it? For example, aggregation:

```
select sum(quantity) 
  into V_quantityS
  ...
```

or perhaps

```
select distinct quantity
```

or even

```
select quantity
...
where rownum = 1
```

---

However, beware: trigger is created on the `transaction` table, and you are selecting from it at the same time which leads to **mutating table** error. What to do with that? Use a compound trigger.